# Dividing an estimate with confidence limits

Tags: confidence-interval

I have an estimated population size for which individual covariates are known for only a smaller sample of the population. So for example, my total population size is estimated to be 26.9 individuals/ha, SE = 4.4, lcl = 19.6, ucl = 36.9. I know that the population is 30% male, and 70% female (from a smaller sample of the population). Is there a way to estimate the total number of males and females with confidence limits? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is long gone and question marginal (and needs more info to be solved)